# There is already an open DataReader associated with this connection which must be closed first C# with Mysql using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

We are using Entity Framework with MySQL mapping. The `DbContext` is injected into the controller.

Injecting the data context:

```
IManageClientService _manageClientService;

public ManageClientController(IManageClientService manageClientService, DataContext dataContext) 
    : base(dataContext) 
{
    this._manageClientService = manageClientService;
}
```

Below is one of the action methods.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Search()
{
    var model = new ClientControlData();

    try
    {
        model.ClientNameList = DataContext.Clients
                                          .Select(c => new SelectListItem 
                                                           {
                                                                Text = c.ClientName, 
                                                                Value = c.ClientId.ToString() 
                                                           });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        olog.Error("An exception occurred while processing Search for Client: " + ex.Message);
        olog.Info("Stack trace for exception: " + ex.StackTrace);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

After completing the execution on page load we are calling another action method with the default parameters it will return JSON. Below is the code for the action method.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetClientDetails(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string clientName)
{
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int pageSize = rows;

    var clientControlData = new List<ClientControlData>();
    var clientData = from w in DataContext.ClientControlDatas
                     select new
                     {
                         w.ControlDataId,
                         w.ClientId,
                         w.WarehouseId,
                         w.WarehouseName,
                         w.RouteUsersAllowed,
                         w.CreateDate,
                         w.CreateBy,
                         w.ModifyDate,
                         w.ModifyBy,
                         w.Status
                     };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientName))
    {
        clientData = clientData.Where(p => p.ClientId.ToString() == clientName.ToString());
    }

    foreach (var obj in clientData)
    {
        var objClientId = obj.ClientId;
        var objClient = DataContext.Clients.Where(x => x.ClientId == objClientId).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Comment: At which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: var objClient = DataContext.Clients.Where(x => x.ClientId == objClientId).FirstOrDefault(); This is the line i am getting error.

Comment: What happen if you convert your `clientData` to list `foreach (var obj in clientData.ToList())`

Comment: This is happing when I am converting into to list. Unknown column 'x.WarehouseName' in 'field list'' @Eric

Comment: I don't see `x.WarehouseName` anywhere in the code.

Comment: ClientControlDatas model is a type of partial class @Eric